# BQL not correctly producing SQL for class extension field, how do I fix this?

Tags: c#, acumatica

I'm writing an extension to filter SO Orders in the Order Process screen by a new SO Line field.

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO 
{ 
   public class SOLineExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine> 
    { 
         #region UsrBin 
         [PXDBString(20)] 
         [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Production Bin")] 
         public virtual string UsrBin { get; set; } 
         public abstract class usrBin : IBqlField { } 
         #endregion 
    } 
}
```

So I've extended SOLine with a new field called 'UsrBin' in an extesion called SOLineExt.

The problem is when I try to call this field from my SOOrderFilterExt,

```
public class SOOrderFilterExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderFilter> 
{ 
   #region UsrProcProdBin 
   [PXString(20)] 
   [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Production Bin", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)] 
   [PXSelector(typeof(Search4<SOLineExt.usrBin, Aggregate<GroupBy<SOLineExt.usrBin>>>))] 
   public virtual string UsrProcProdBin { get; set; } 
   public abstract class usrProcProdBin : IBqlField { } 
   #endregion 
}
```

the valid bql name of the field seems to be SoLineExt.UsrBin. When the query is run it throws the error "The multi-part identifier "SOLineExt.UsrBin" could not be bound." Looking at debug information it appears the SQL being generated is actually looking for a the table SOLineExt.UsrBin instead of SOLine.UsrBin where the field actually is.

How do I control the BQL to SQL output to look at the SOLine table? Or is there a more fundamental mistake here? I can provide code samples if that would help.

Comment: Can you show your declaration of SOLineEXt?

Comment: `namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOLineExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine>
    {
        #region UsrBin
        [PXDBString(20)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Production Bin")]

        public virtual string UsrBin { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrBin : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
    }
}` I don't think this is anything strange. It's just an extra field attached to the SOLine class. As I understand it, the DAC names is SOLineExt.UsrBin, but the table it's stored in is SOLine in the database, which I verified through SQL Studio.

Comment: can you please show code on how you make a call in SOOrderFilterExt?

Comment: I suspect field is used in a projection and Acumatica ORM uses the original table name in SQL query instead of the projection alias table it should use. It's a hard issue because it can't be fixed through customization. One (very bad) workaround that sometimes influence the ORM to use the proper alias is to put the SOLine in a different custom namespace then copy/paste the whole SOLine DAC in that namespace. When ORM picks up the extension it uses the copy of SOLine and for whatever reason it does use the correct Alias.

Comment: I will have to check that out. It looks like I was actually mistaken where the issue is happening. It's when I attempt to use a PXSelector from another extension in SOOrderFilterExt. When it tries to automatically find the available bins using to fill the bin selection field on the So Order Processing screen.

Comment: ` public class SOOrderFilterExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderFilter>
    {
        #region UsrProcProdBin
        [PXString(20)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Production Bin", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search4<SOLineExt.usrBin, Aggregate<GroupBy<SOLineExt.usrBin>>>))]
        

        public virtual string UsrProcProdBin { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrProcProdBin : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
    }`

Comment: It seems that the PXSelector is actually what's having the problem with trying to create the SQL call to the database.

Comment: When you say call, you mean click on magnifying glass?

Comment: Yes, when you click on the magnifying glass to open the selector.